# How to get variable from parent url or parent iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, html

How to get the variable from parent window url to child iframe or get the variable from parent iframe to child iframe?

I have index.html file which have iframe who have the form the form send the data to checker.php than this files forward the user to example.php with variable i.e., `http://www.example.com/sample.php?variable=variable` the example.php have iframe and the iframe have **iframe called authenticate.php .**

Comment: Do parent and child come from the same domain?

Comment: This is tagged "php" and "javascript", what language do you care about?

Comment: The second paragraph of your question shows that some data is already being passed. So what is the problem?

Comment: What is HTML 5 specific about this? (since you have tagged it as such)

Comment: @Quentin sorry for late reply actually i need the solution fast thats why i tag both so that i can use javascript or php to get variable data and i tag html5 because maybe html5 grate developers knows the solution of this

Comment: for those who down voted this and want to close may i known the reason please 
because as i see there are many similar questions like this but they don't full fills my need that why i posted here is it wrong to ask a question here which you already tried to find a answer and also please want to known that which rules is braking thanks

Comment: I still can't tell if you are trying to pass the data via JavaScript or PHP.

Comment: @Quentin no problem as you known its depend on the person that he want share his knowledge and help others but some time they want but they dont have time so maybe you have the some reason for not answering but thanks for your comment and time :)

Comment: @DanishIqbal — The reason I can't tell is because you haven't told us.

Comment: what i yet not told you ?
sorry for that and thanks for editing the answer

Comment: @Quentin i like php more than javascript because its easy and very nice function and on the other hand javascript required more coding and more knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eugen Rieck is trying to find out, content can only communicate through iframes when they originate from the same domain, otherwise you will run into the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

To communicate with a document in an iframe you can use

```
var frame=window.document.getElementById('yourFrame');
var doc=frame.contentWindow.document;
```

You can then communicate with the elements of the document in the iframe.

I would include the variable that you are trying to "grab" in example.php as a hidden text input. You can do this by running a querystring:

```
var queryString = new Object;
var qstr = window.location.search.substring(1);
var params = qstr.split('&')
for (var 1=0; i<params.length; i++) {
var pair = params[i].split('=');
queryString[pair[0]]=pair[1];

var variable = queryString['variable'] //find the value of variable
document.write("<input style='visibility:hidden' id='variable' type='text' value='"+ variable +"'></input>");
```

Once that is in the iframed document, pull it back out in the parent by using:

```
var variable = doc.getElementById('variable').value;
```

and bob's your uncle.

Let me know if this helps....

----EDIT----

Alternatively, if you were to write this in a function in the parent page, to invoke it from the child page you could use:

```
function callParentFunction() {

            parent.getVariable();
            return false;

}
```

You could run an onload to call this  or something

Comment: i am now, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: can we discuss it tomorrow because i am at home and at home i don't do office work

Comment: do you think that my question as something wrong actually i want to known whats wrong in my question why some vote it down

Comment: http://uk.linkedin.com/in/pdbevan is my linkedin. it is a bit unclear who are the parents and children but send me a mail on linkedin and we will go from there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8340/discussion-between-philip-bevan-and-danish-iqbal)

Comment: Thank you so much for you kind corporation my problem is solve :)